# Pronounciation of Sanskrit words

Tags: mantras, sanskrit, shloka, resource

Sanskrit is a very pure language and care must be taken when pronouncing its words in a Sloka or a Mantra. Are there any websites or resources that help in learning the "correct" pronunciation of the words in Audio format?

P.S. - I have enrolled in a Sanskrit language and I am trying to pronounce some words myself, I am not able to figure out whether I am pronouncing it correctly.

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks in Advance :-)

Comment: This is off topic for this site. May be good for language SE. Check this once: https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/search?q=Sanskrit

Comment: English  being a non-phonetic language ,( ie. the spelling does not determine the pronounciation of a word .for an eg. word *read* , pronounced in  *I like to read*  differs from *I ve read the book*) , so pronounciation should be known at word level  ..This is not the case in many of the phonetic languages like Sanskrit.. Here, learning to pronounce thru uccharana sthanas , at the level of alphabets(varnamalas) helps. along with some knowledge on sandhis that connect morphemes.

Comment: when it comes to shlokas, chandas sets the rhythm,/pattern that distinguishes it from normal reading ,also lends a scope for remembering it.
youtube channel 
*Learn Sanskrit Online : vyoma-samskrta-pathasala*
would be of some online help.(may be , this seems  to be off topic as in prev. comment) Posting this Q in Sanskrit language forums , may offer more help

Comment: Thank you @Athrey